# Connection of a $G$-principal bundle as a section of a vector bundle?

Tags: lie-groups, principal-bundles

In what follows all manifolds, Lie groups and mappings are meant to be $C^\infty$.

Let $\pi:M\longrightarrow B$ be a left $G$-principal bundle. A **connection** on this bundle is a map $H$ which assigns to every $p\in M$ a vector subspace $H_p\subseteq T_pM$ such that:

$(i)$ $T_pM=H_p\oplus V_p$ (where $V_p$ are the vertical tangent vectors to $p$);

$(ii)$ $(dR_g)_p(H_p)=H_{g\cdot p}$ (I'm not sure if this is right, the notation of the paper I'm following is outdated so I'm writing here what I think it makes sense);

$(iii)$ $H$ is differentiable: Given any smooth vector field $X$ on $M$ if $X^h$ denotes its horizontal part then $X^h$ is smooth.

Can I realize $H$ as a section of a vector bundle (with additional properties)?

Thanks

Comment: You can view $H$ as a section (over $M$) of a [Grassmanian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmannian) fibre bundle built from $TM$, but to view $H$ as a section of a vector bundle you'd have to construct a vector space whose elements are _subspaces_ of the tangent spaces of $M$ "in a natural way".

Comment: The Grassmanian will do, thanks =) Could you recommend me a reference for such a construction?

Comment: I don't know of a reference offhand (maybe Griffiths and Harris for the complex case...?), but depending how much detail you need, it's straightforward to accomplish from scratch. The idea is, the construction of a Grassmannian of a vector space is sufficiently natural that it can be applied fibrewise to a vector bundle (here $TM$, the tangent bundle of the total space of your principal bundle).

Comment: Ok, I'll think about it. Thanks.